# Plot day of week below time on x-axis

Tags: r, date, plot, posixct

I have a dataset with hours and their frequency.  After plotting with:

```
plot(roundedHours$Var1, roundedHours$Freq, xlab = "time", ylab = "frequency")
lines(roundedHours$Var1, roundedHours$Freq)
```

The graph produced looks like this:

[image]

I would like to add a second x-axis below the existing one that shows the day of the week. Just to see if I could add the first and last day int he range, I tried

```
axis(side=4, at=c("2017-09-08 20:00:00 EDT","2017-09-15 20:00:00 EDT"), labels=c("Friday","Friday"))
```

but this produces the error

```
Error in axis(side = 4, at = c("2017-09-08 20:00:00 EDT", "2017-09-15 20:00:00 EDT"),  : 
  no locations are finite
In addition: Warning message:
In axis(side = 4, at = c("2017-09-08 20:00:00 EDT", "2017-09-15 20:00:00 EDT"),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

How would one add the day of the week below the current x-axis? 
Here is the data:

```
> dput(roundedHours)
structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1504915200, 1504918800, 1504922400, 
1504926000, 1504929600, 1504933200, 1504936800, 1504940400, 1504944000, 
1504947600, 1504951200, 1504954800, 1504958400, 1504962000, 1504965600, 
1504969200, 1504972800, 1504976400, 1504980000, 1504983600, 1504987200, 
1504990800, 1504994400, 1504998000, 1505001600, 1505005200, 1505008800, 
1505012400, 1505016000, 1505019600, 1505023200, 1505026800, 1505030400, 
1505034000, 1505037600, 1505041200, 1505044800, 1505048400, 1505052000, 
1505055600, 1505059200, 1505062800, 1505066400, 1505070000, 1505073600, 
1505077200, 1505080800, 1505084400, 1505088000, 1505091600, 1505095200, 
1505098800, 1505102400, 1505106000, 1505109600, 1505113200, 1505116800, 
1505120400, 1505124000, 1505127600, 1505131200, 1505134800, 1505138400, 
1505142000, 1505145600, 1505149200, 1505152800, 1505156400, 1505160000, 
1505163600, 1505167200, 1505170800, 1505174400, 1505178000, 1505181600, 
1505185200, 1505188800, 1505192400, 1505196000, 1505199600, 1505203200, 
1505206800, 1505210400, 1505214000, 1505217600, 1505221200, 1505224800, 
1505228400, 1505232000, 1505235600, 1505239200, 1505242800, 1505246400, 
1505250000, 1505253600, 1505257200, 1505260800, 1505264400, 1505268000, 
1505271600, 1505275200, 1505278800, 1505282400, 1505286000, 1505289600, 
1505293200, 1505296800, 1505300400, 1505304000, 1505307600, 1505311200, 
1505314800, 1505318400, 1505322000, 1505325600, 1505329200, 1505332800, 
1505336400, 1505340000, 1505343600, 1505347200, 1505350800, 1505354400, 
1505358000, 1505361600, 1505365200, 1505368800, 1505372400, 1505376000, 
1505379600, 1505383200, 1505386800, 1505390400, 1505394000, 1505397600, 
1505401200, 1505404800, 1505408400, 1505412000, 1505415600, 1505419200, 
1505422800, 1505426400, 1505430000, 1505433600, 1505437200, 1505440800, 
1505444400, 1505448000, 1505451600, 1505455200, 1505458800, 1505462400, 
1505466000, 1505469600, 1505473200, 1505476800, 1505480400, 1505484000, 
1505487600, 1505491200, 1505494800, 1505498400, 1505502000, 1505505600, 
1505509200, 1505512800, 1505516400, 1505520000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Freq = c(3332L, 7781L, 7991L, 6456L, 
4511L, 3289L, 3455L, 3397L, 3778L, 2682L, 2512L, 2407L, 3376L, 
3675L, 4992L, 5815L, 6229L, 7696L, 7917L, 8255L, 8356L, 8764L, 
7915L, 8048L, 7016L, 5896L, 7131L, 5808L, 6378L, 6552L, 5090L, 
3798L, 3514L, 3775L, 3390L, 2538L, 3197L, 3552L, 4171L, 5315L, 
6319L, 7740L, 9281L, 9443L, 8704L, 8223L, 7648L, 9663L, 9143L, 
7441L, 6701L, 5058L, 4962L, 4414L, 3767L, 3202L, 3382L, 3528L, 
4176L, 4625L, 6533L, 5890L, 6029L, 6366L, 6722L, 8339L, 7511L, 
8143L, 9661L, 10582L, 11232L, 8612L, 7886L, 8054L, 6646L, 5900L, 
5517L, 3004L, 1895L, 1378L, 2272L, 2599L, 2132L, 3404L, 5035L, 
4749L, 4273L, 4487L, 5698L, 4210L, 7204L, 8176L, 10905L, 9340L, 
10437L, 8771L, 6268L, 6629L, 5508L, 4600L, 4341L, 2243L, 2000L, 
1731L, 1373L, 1800L, 3600L, 3740L, 4168L, 3920L, 5269L, 5879L, 
5483L, 6837L, 7521L, 9513L, 10540L, 10513L, 9815L, 9510L, 8171L, 
6255L, 6731L, 6546L, 4865L, 4835L, 2988L, 3081L, 2646L, 2222L, 
2709L, 4406L, 5205L, 7541L, 6582L, 5871L, 5660L, 8002L, 8421L, 
8480L, 11122L, 11756L, 12756L, 9976L, 9332L, 8458L, 7741L, 8384L, 
5960L, 4638L, 3235L, 2864L, 2597L, 2484L, 2820L, 3182L, 4284L, 
5662L, 5763L, 6217L, 4804L, 7484L, 7981L, 9112L, 9655L, 9578L, 
9669L, 9020L, 3908L), weekday = c("Friday", "Friday", "Friday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", 
"Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", 
"Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", 
"Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", 
"Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", 
"Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"
)), .Names = c("Var1", "Freq", "weekday"), row.names = c(NA, 
-169L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think you can only add axes using actual values which appear in the raw data you are plotting.  So you might be able to back calculate those dates from the raw data, for each day.

Comment: That's already in the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
ax.dt <- seq(as.POSIXct("2017-09-08 0:00:00 EDT"),
             as.POSIXct("2017-10-15 0:00:00 EDT"), by=86400)
axis(side=1, at=ax.dt, labels=weekdays(ax.dt), line=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works, but I would like for each day to fit within a range (a day is between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59)